# Does it make sense to include GDP/capita and Population in the same OLS model

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity, logarithm

I got good results in my OLS model by using as explanatory variables: 
**GDP/capita** = GDP/Population and the **Population**.

Do you think  that is an issue to include both in the model (multicollinearity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not expect this to be a problem, at all. The whole point of GDP/capita is that it is a way of representing GDP that makes sense across different values of the population - or in other words is "independent" (perhaps not in the strict statistical sense of the word, but to a "first approximation" [again not in the strict mathematical sense of the word]) of population size.

In fact, if anything, I would expect multicollinearity more if you used GDP and population together as predictors. However, I would suspect that since there's plenty of small countries with a low and a high GDP per capita, and the same for large countries, that you would not get truly severe multicollinearity even in that case.

Comment: It is very enlightening, many thanks.